# How to set border of another element when an input control has focus?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I have a form with various input controls set up like this:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <small>
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </small>
</div>
```

And I have a SCSS file that changes the border width on active and focus:

```
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus:active  {
    border-width: $input-focus-width !important;
}
```

Currently I'm getting this result:

[image: Inputcontrol]

How can I set the border with of the `input-group-text` element when the input control is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the element immediately placed after `.form-control` with the following selector:

`.form-control:focus + .input-group-append .input-group-text`

In your case:

```css
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus:active,
.form-control:focus + .input-group-append .input-group-text {
    border-width: 2px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-envelope">icon</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <small>
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to select the `.input-group-append` div then the descendant selector to grab the div with the `.input-group-text` class as below. Bootstrap styles the border with a slightly darker gray so I've put an outline property on there too so you can definitley see it working.

```css
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus:active {
  border-width: 3px !important;
}

.form-control:is(:focus, :focus:active)+.input-group-append .input-group-text {
  border-width: 3px !important;
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  /* added this because the border is styled a light gray colour and not so easy to see*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <small>
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </small>
</div>
```